# How to create UI in Meteor 1.4 with the templates

Tags: javascript, user-interface, templates, meteor

I have to create a collaboration app with Meteor, but I'm stuck at creating the UI. 
I want to have some buttons for the different pages, but I would like to do this using the templates so that I don't have to load another page.
The problem is that I am not able to change the templates with a button click. 
Does anyone have a small code snippet I can use to fix my problem?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

make the button clicks `this.setState({templateName: template})`.

Then in your render:

```
if (this.setState.templateName == 'template1'){
    <Template1 />
}else if (this.setState.templateName == 'template2'){
    <Template2 />
}else etc
```

You can also see a full demo I made here: https://github.com/Frazer/meteor-react-nav/tree/master/lib/jsx   - It renders in a more complex way than the code snippet I just gave you here.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! Can you maybe explain this code snippet in a bit more detail? Like which code goes where? I'm really new to Meteor and the learning isn't going so well...

Comment: Hi Milan, I recommend you look at https://github.com/Frazer/meteor-react-nav/tree/master/lib/jsx